# Can I create a CustomTaskPane in Microsoft Project using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-project, office-addins

Visual Studio 2015.

I've followed this brief [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx) to create a CustomTaskPane in Word. I have managed to get it working. I would like to do the same for Microsoft Project but I fall at the first hurdle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();

            Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane ctp = CustomTaskPanes.Add(uc, "Title");
            ctp.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The above works for a Word AddIn but I get the following error when I try to do it for a Project AddIn:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'CustomTaskPanes' does not exist in the current context    MSProjectAddIn1 D:\DevProjects\MSProjectAddIn1\MSProjectAddIn1\ThisAddIn.cs 17

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using MSProject = Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;


namespace MSProjectAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();

            Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane ctp = CustomTaskPanes.Add(uc, "Title");
            ctp.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Has anyone created a CustomTaskPane for MSProject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of Googling, I found an answer not long after posting to stack exchange - not sure why but the way to access `CustomTaskPanes` is different in MSProject:

```
UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();

Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPaneCollection customPaneCollection;
customPaneCollection = Globals.Factory.CreateCustomTaskPaneCollection(null, null, "Panes", "Panes", this);

Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane ctp = customPaneCollection.Add(uc, "Title");
ctp.Visible = true;
```